# How it is possible to use a variable as a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to learn express.js and then i encountered these statements.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
```

So now how is it possible to write this variable "express" as "express()".
Is it possible to do this with any type of variable?

Comment: Here you can read about it https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2018/05/30/understanding-how-expressjs-works/ express()  calls the createApplication() function from lib/express.js

Answer (score 6):

Functions are first-class objects in JavaScript, they aren't special like they are in some other languages. They're just objects that are callable. Since they're objects, you can pass them around:

```js
function example() {
    console.log("Hi there");
}

const e = example;
e(); // "Hi there"
```

You can also put additional properties on them (something that Express also does). Here's an example:

```js
function example() {
    console.log("Hi there");
}

example.prop = 42;

const e = example;
e(); // "Hi there"

console.log(example.prop); // 42
console.log(e.prop);       // 42 -- since `e` and `example` both refer to the same function
```

> Is it possible to do this with any type of variable?

JavaScript variables don't have a type as they do in strongly-typed languages. The value the variable holds has a type, but the variable doesn't; a variable can hold a number one moment, a string the next, a function after that...

```js
function example() {
    console.log("Hi there");
}

let e = example;
e(); // "Hi there"

e = 42;
console.log(e); // 42

e = "Hi there";
console.log(e); // "Hi there"
```

If you want variables, parameters, and such to have types (so you can't put a string in a variable that's expected to contain a number), consider using TypeScript, Flow, or even just JSDoc combined with robust IDE support. These layer a type system on top of JavaScript (to varying degrees).

Getting back to your question: You can do it with any *variable*, but not with any type of value. You can't call a number:

```js
let e = 42;
e(); // TypeError: e is not a function
```

You can only call functions or other host-provided callable objects¹ (which don't absolutely have to be true functions, but it's uncommon now for hosts to provide callable objects that aren't actual functions, it was problematic).

---

¹ Specifically, in spec terms, any object that supports the [[[Call]] internal operation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-additional-essential-internal-methods-of-function-objects).

Comment: Now i'm able to understand some things. so functions are also objects. But i'm still confused,. Like why write "const app = express();" and why simply not "const app = express;" or why not skip this statement completely . We can access the contents of express.js module using that "express" object right. So why even bother to include "const app = express();".

Comment: @JoseJayant - Because the `express` function creates and returns an [`Application`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app) object, and that's what you want to use when building your Express app (mostly; the `express` function itself has some methods you might also use, but the primary ones are on the `Application` object, not the `express` function).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this with any variable but there is something called arrow functions for example

`const test = () => {}`
and you can call this function by saying

`test()`

within () it takes input and within {} you specify what it does or returns

require fetches whatever you specified so i'm guessing it is equal to a function

To do this with any variable it must be an arrow function. Hope I helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Definitely yes, you are talking about JavaScript **inline functions**, [check this out](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-inline-function-in-javascript/)!

For example, you can do:

```
function example() {
  return 1;
}

const execute = example();

console.log(execute) // returns 1
```