# How is it possible to access and use the functions in express.js module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

If i want to create an express app i can write these two statements.

```
const express = require(“express“);
const app = express();
```

By using this "app" object I can access various functions within express() like get(),listen(),use() etc.
My Question is how these functions are returned by express() so that these are accessible using the "app" object. Does it return an object consisting of functions or there is some other way?

What is the sorcery behind this technology?

Comment: `express()` creates and returns an object. It works similar to a constructor. `express` is open source and well documented. You could read the documentation and the source code.

Comment: "Does it return an object consisting of functions" yes.

Comment: Study about factory functions.

Comment: You can take a look at the documentation and source code on Github. ```express``` consists of a function that when called returns an object composed by functions, you can call it "an instance of an express app".

Comment: A similar question was asked about 2 hours ago also about express() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66075802/how-it-is-possible-to-use-a-variable-as-a-function-in-javascript/66075839#66075839

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the source code of express, `app` is just an object with methods like get, listen, use, and so on...

https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/application.js